# Building a custom report

Tags: magento-1.6, reports

I would like to produce a report in Magento that tells me which products customers are using the notify me feature on.
The report might contain something along the lines of SKU and numer of people who have clicked notify me on that item, and maybe the most recent date occurrance?

Thinking out load there - but you get the idea. Is there anything already in existence, and if not, does anyone know how I might go about building such a report?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I would extend from the `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection`, replace it's `_initSelect()` with your own query, and display in a grid block.

Answer (score 0):

I know of one custom report writer extension. You can find it on the developer's site here: http://extensionsstore.biz/extension-packages/custom-report-writer.html. It uses SQL queries for any information stored in your Magento Shopping Cart’s database.